# Adjusting bounds in Leaflet (R) with sf column

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf

I'm making a little app in Shiny that holds data for countries and regions, and where users will be able to choose a region. Then the idea is that the leaflet map that I have in the app will zoom in and focus on the chosen region (i.e. user clicks "Europe" and the map zooms in on Europe).

I can't figure out how I should go about using the simple features`geometry` column as the filter for the leaflet map. Here's a simply example (not in Shiny, but the problem is not Shiny-related, I imagine).

```
library(rnaturalearth) 
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

# sf data:
earth <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>% 
  select(Region = region_un, geometry)

# little dataset:
df <- data_frame(
  Region = c("Europe", "Africa", "Asia", "Oceania", "Americas"),
  Score = c(0.85, 0.77, 0.81, 0.93, 0.79)
)
# join:
df <- full_join(df, earth)

# simulate what I'm doing in Shiny:
input <- list()
input$region <- "Europe"

df2 <- filter(df, Region == input$region)

leaflet(df2) %>% addTiles()
```

This produces:
[image]

Which is the same as if I had used `df` (the unfiltered dataframe). Any ideas on how I could go about this? I couldn't find it in the Shiny/leaflet docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `sf::st_coordinates` to extract the values from `df2$geometry`, get the average latitude and longitude then use `leaflet::setView()` to focus on our region of interest:

```
library(sf)
coords <- st_coordinates(df2$geometry)
lng <- mean(coords[,1])
lat <- mean(coords[,2])

leaflet(df2) %>% addTiles() %>%
    setView(lng, lat, zoom = 3) # 3 for "continent" level
```

[image]

There are some special methods for updating `leaflet` maps in a Shiny setting mainly `leafletProxy()`, those are described pretty well in the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I wasn't aware of the `st_coordinates()` function, very useful.