# Setting Boundaries of Leaflet with sf geometry in R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I would like to use the `sf` package to extract a bounding box (e.g., `st_bbox` ) and pass these coords to a leaflet using `fitBounds`.

What is the best way to do this? There is a similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352567/adjusting-bounds-in-leaflet-r-with-sf-column):
I don't want to take an average of all coordinates since we already have a bounding box that could be used AND we don't want to have to set the zoom using `setView`. An example of what I'm currently trying -

Taking the great state of Indiana:

```
require(USAboundaries);require(sf)
state <- us_boundaries(states="Indiana")
st_bbox(state)


       xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
    -88.11186  37.78194 -84.78395  41.75956
```

I'd like to get that easily into a format that Leaflet's `fitBounds` can interpret. Something like this perhaps?:

```
map.fitBounds([
  [-88.11186, 37.78194],
  [-84.78395, 41.75956]
);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(USAboundaries)

state <- us_boundaries(states = "Indiana")

bbox <- st_bbox(state) %>% 
  as.vector()

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  fitBounds(bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3], bbox[4])
```

[image]

Comment: Works a treat. Similar to what I was thinking and more efficient than the mean coordinates solution I found on multiple threads.